# "Portfolio Icon" link between "before" and "after" links in portfolio

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to modify a Wordpress theme I bought. Here is my Wordpress site: [www.clewster.com](http://www.clewster.com) and here is the theme that I am using: http://themetrust.com/themes/ridge/

**The Problem:**

On a single Portfolio page item (when you click on "muse band poster" for example) when you scroll down but stop right before the comments section, there is a "previous" and "next" link that links to the previous and next projects, but instead of saying "previous" and "next" it just says the name of the project and little arrows to click on.

**What I want it to do:**

In between those "previous" and "next" links, I want to add a little icon (The Font-Awesome cheatsheet code: fa-th) and have it link back to the portfolio page, so that users don't have to go to the left navigation to go back.

The problem is that I don't know how to insert this new link in PHP. Opening up the .php files of the Ridge theme, the only php files that have any mentioning of "previous" and "after" links are **content-single.php** and **content-project.php** with the following php codes, respectively:

```
<?php
wp_link_pages( array(
'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'ridge' ),
'after'  => '</div>',
) );
?>
```

and

```
wp_link_pages( array(
'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' .   __( 'Pages:', 'ridge' ) . '</span>',
'after'       => '</div>',
'link_before' => '<span>',
'link_after'  => '</span>',
'pagelink'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'ridge' )   . ' </span>%',
'separator'   => '<span class="screen-reader-text">, </span>',
) );
?>
```

**What I need to Know:**

1) Which PHP file do I need to modify

2) What do I write in PHP to insert in the array (if the solution calls for it, it might be a totally different method) the new link with the icon?

If I'm not on the right track at all, please let me know.